# How to write Load data local infile in unix shell

Tags: mysql, unix

I need to write below statement in unix bash script. I am making mysql connection and passing this whole things in double quotes. I am getting problem in enclosed by clause.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

it should be written like

```
"LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;"
```

Comment: In retrospect, I should have asked you *what have you tried?* and maybe even downvoted this instead of answering it. Please c.f. [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking a good question, and [this reference](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) of explanations of things you *really* should and should not do. Always show your effort, what errors you are getting, and a simple way to reproduce the problem. The better your question, the better your answers should be. What searches did you try?  Lucky for you, my ADHD is often too interested to be very strict...

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of quoting, but doable.

```
$: sql=$'LOAD DATA INFILE \'data.csv\' INTO TABLE tbl_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'\"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\' IGNORE 1 LINES;'
$: echo "$sql"
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Just be *aware* that the quotes are now part of the data as it's handed off to mysql, which will hopefully reparse it accordingly. If I pass it unquoted to `printf`, notice it still has all the intended quoting characters in place.

```
$: printf "%s\n" $sql
LOAD
DATA
INFILE
'data.csv'
INTO
TABLE
tbl_name
FIELDS
TERMINATED
BY
','
ENCLOSED
BY
'"'
LINES
TERMINATED
BY
'\r\n'
IGNORE
1
LINES;
```